# How to increase the upload limit for files on a Symfony 2 form?

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony

I have a form in Symfony where the user uploads files to. These files can be up to 50Mb in size.

However, when I try to upload a file that is about 10Mb (before this, the files were no bigger than 7.2Mb) the form reloads with this error:

> The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file

This is a validation error, it doesn't appear as a proper Symfony2 error.

I've set the `upload_max_filesize` setting in the PHP.ini file to 50MB, so a 10MB file shouldn't be an issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to set both of these in the php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 50M

upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Comment: Or use `.user.ini` [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: Why not using ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "XXM") in the action ? In this way you adjust this limit just where you need it, no ?

Comment: @David according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442270/ini-setupload-max-filesize-200m-not-working-in-php what you propose (and it is waht I wanted) seems impossible.