# ini_set("upload_max_filesize","200M") not working in php

Tags: file-upload, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [overriding upload_max_filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949415/overriding-upload-max-filesize)

i use these code for change upload file size :-

```
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize').'<br/>';
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");
echo ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
```

BUT I GOT

```
2M
2M
```

which is set in php.ini.

i want to change file upload size limit.

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards?

Comment: [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) is only [PHP_INI_PERDIR changeable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

1. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

> upload_max_filesize   "2M"    **PHP_INI_PERDIR**

1. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

> **PHP_INI_PERDIR**     Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

So you can't use `ini_set` for this.

Comment: using php_value upload_max_filesize 500M and php_value post_max_size 500M in my htaccess file worked great! Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You need to increase [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/post_max_size) as well.

> To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize

You may also need to increase [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/memory_limit)

> If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

As others have pointed out, `upload_max_filesize` cannot be changed at runtime (using `ini_set`). However, once you have changed it correctly *you will still need to increase these values*.

Comment: The issue is that the actual `upload_max_filesize` setting is not updated, not that actual file uploads fail.

Comment: @lanzz Thanks, missed that. However once that issue is fixed, his file uploads will still fail, due to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) says:

> The available options are K (for Kilobytes), M (for Megabytes) and G (for Gigabytes; available since PHP 5.1.0), these are case insensitive. Anything else assumes bytes. 1M equals one Megabyte or 1048576 bytes. 1K equals one Kilobyte or 1024 bytes. ***You may not use these shorthand notations outside of php.ini, instead use an integer value of bytes***.