# How set POST size limit on a per-script basis?

Tags: php, post, limit, max

ETA: some have suggested `ini_set()` but it's my understanding this is a server-side setting; I need per-script independence at run-time. E.g., three scripts simultaneously running like this: x.php uses 2k, y.php uses 4k, and z.php uses 8k.

How do I programmatically set a limit on the POST max size on a *per-script basis* (i.e., not server-wide)?

For instance in Perl one would simply do this in each script, thus allowing each one to set its own limit at run-time:

```
# The $POST_MAX variable also applies to the combined size of all the elements
# in a form. Therefore, you can set this variable to keep people from pasting
# huge amounts of junk into text fields, too.
$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 2;
```

I realize there is a setting in php.ini to limit the maximum POST size for *all* PHP scripts:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
```

But I want to know how to do this on a per-script basis (because each script will have its own limits).

Note: Presumably one can set a limit in Apache httpd.conf and/or in a .htaccess but I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `ini_set` and then set your php setting as you like.

**Example**

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '60M');     
ini_set('max_execution_time', '999');
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '60M');
```

Comment: Isn't that a server-wide setting, one that will affect all scripts? For example, I need x.php to use 2k, y.php to use 4k, and z.php to use 8k.

Comment: @Scavokovich - you are right, but i think only for the time that script is being executed, but still that does not sound like a perfect solution

Comment: yes its server setting but you can make it as common file and include it wherever you want..so it won't affect to other file that do not have included common file

Comment: ini_set() will affect only the current script runtime, overriding the server-wide setting; thus, you can set different values on a script-by-script basis.

Comment: `ini_set()` does not work for `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize` anymore (as of Dec. 2020) as theu are set as ***PHP_INI_PERDIR*** in PHP - we can only change it in `ini`, `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` - [SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442270/ini-setupload-max-filesize-200m-not-working-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

To change the ini settings on per script basis you can use:

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M')
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can do it in your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

or you can use `ini_set` php function which almost is disabled by host provider.

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '60M');
```