# ini_set('post_max_size', '200M') did not work in php 5.4

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, php-5.4, ini-set

ini_set('post_max_size', '200M') did not work in php 5.4
i had use following method.
.htaccess , user.ini , php.ini , php5.ini but it did not effect of post_max_size. it remain on 64M.  it change the memory limit and execution time but did not change the post_max_size.

phpinfo(); system information
PHP Version 5.4.29
System  Linux gator4143.hostgator.com 3.2.54 #9 SMP Thu Feb 13 08:17:11 CST 2014 x86_64
Virtual Directory Support   disabled

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: You can't use `ini_set` for this - [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13442343/2518525)

Comment: You have to change max upload size as well

Answer (score 2):

All those you mention are configuration files. In configuration files you simply cannot run PHP code because they are not scripts. You have to use the corresponding syntax (just check other directives on the same file). Typically:

- php.ini, .user.ini → `post_max_size = "200M"`
- .htaccess, httpd.conf → `php_value post_max_size 200MB`

Comment: php.ini in a project directory 
post_max_size= "2000M";
upload_max_filesize= "2000M";
memory_limit= "3000M";
max_execution_time= "2592000";
max_input_time= "2592000";
session.gc_maxlifetime= "1200";

Comment: htaccess, http.conf

php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 2592000
php_value max_input_time 2592000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200

Comment: php file 
ini_set('safe_mode ', 'Off'); 
ini_set('max_input_time', '2592000');
ini_set('memory_limit', '3000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '200M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '200M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '2592000');
ini_set('max_file_uploads', '100');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '1200');

Comment: If you need to provide further info, please use the **edit** link and add it to the question itself. Code in comments is unreadable. If you're asking for some clarification about my answer, please explain your doubts, not just dump a bunch a code.

Comment: i get my point it will not exceed the limit . i am using share package. past_max_size only increase in vpn server or buy your own server.

Comment: That's not true. [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) is clearly documented as [PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) since PHP/4.2.4. I'm changing it all the time.