# Symfony2 invalid token with big files

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm having problem with token and file field form.

The validation of the form is like this:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
        'fields' => array(
            'file' => new File(
                array(
                    'maxSize' => '2M',
                    'mimeTypes' => array(
                        'application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf',
                        'image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif',
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )
    ));

    return array(
        'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint
}
```

When I upload a invalid size file(~5MB) I get this error which is what I hope:

```
The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2M bytes
```

But when I upload a too big file(~30MB) the error changes:

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form
The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file
```

The problem is the error token. I've in my form the {{ form_rest(form) }} code. I think the error change is because of this: [How to increase the upload limit for files on a Symfony 2 form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795121/how-to-increase-the-upload-limit-for-files-on-a-symfony-2-form)

I don't want to increase the upload limit. I want the token error doesn't show.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I didn't found a solution for this. I set the csrf_portection to false in getDefaultOptions but this is to avoid the error message. If you find a solution, please ping me.

Answer (score 7):

PHP (not Symfony) rejects the file if it is bigger than your configured values in:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

Because of this the csrf-error is thrown.

If you want to avoid this you have to increase the upload limit. It is the only way. If you add your file-constraint this should be no risk.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

[CSRF token invalid & upload file too large errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JQDo.jpg)

This two errors are form generated errors, and besides the field errors, they will appear when any exception occurs inside the form.

In this case of uploading files **CSRF token invalid error** appears due to **post_max_size** parameter in **php.ini** configuration file and
**upload file too large error** appears due to **upload_max_filesize** parameter in **php.ini** configuration file.

**SOLUTION:**

1- You can increase the value in the configuration files.

2- You can have field validation and comment or omit the line of form_errors inside your **template.html.twig**, notice that this solution will remove all kind of form generated errors notifications.

Example of **template.html.twig:**

```
<div class="form">
{{ form_start(form) }}

   {{ form_errors(form) }} --> before 
   {# {{ form_errors(form) }} #} --> after

   <div class="field">
      {{ form_label(form.field) }}
      {{ form_errors(form.field) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.field) }}
   </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your **Entity.php** you need to specify the "[maxSize](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html#maxsize)" property to your [Assert file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

For the exemple, the value "2147483648" equals 2GB.

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
public $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="2147483648")
 */
public $file;
```