# max upload size php with symfony2

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, upload

I have this form with file input that post to an iframe.

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ path('lesson_upload') }}" target="uploadFrame" method="post">
    <label for="uploadFile">Image :</label>
    <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" type="file" />
    <br /><br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div id="uploadInfos">
    <div id="uploadStatus">Aucun upload en cours</div>
    <iframe hidden id="uploadFrame" name="uploadFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

It seems that there is an upload size limit of 2M.

I have edited all the php.ini to increase this limit.
And there is no limitation on any .htaccess.

Is there a limitation due to symfony ?

Maybe a configuration file ?

EDIT : PHP script

```
public function lessonUploadAction(Request $request)
    {
        $error    = NULL;
        $filename = NULL;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile']) && $_FILES['uploadFile']['error'] === 0)
        {

            $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])['filename'];
            $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])['extension'];

        // On déplace le fichier depuis le répertoire temporaire vers $targetpath
            $doc = new Document();
            $doc->setName($filename);
            $doc->setAuthor($this->getUser());
            $now = new \DateTime();
            $doc->setDate($now);
            $em->persist($doc);
            $em->flush();
            $targetpath = getcwd() . '/ressources/library/documents/' . $doc->getSlug() . '.' . $ext;
            if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $targetpath))
            {
                $error = 'OK';
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "Échec de l'enregistrement !";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Aucun fichier réceptionné !';
        }
        return new JsonResponse($this->container->get('jms_serializer')->serialize(['name' => $filename, 'slug' => $doc->getSlug(), 'ext' => $ext], 'json')); // doublement jsonifié ?
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: did you use any bundle for uploading files? can you share your php script of upload?

Comment: you shouldnt manage file uploads on your own. For example there is the vich uploader bundle, where u just say in your entities, whether this should be an upload field or not. And everything else goes automatically.

Comment: I do not use any bundle for uploading files... I edited to add the php script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the maximum size limit of over all post request as well.

```
post_max_size
```

This value also need to be enlarged in php.ini file, try and check that. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795121/how-to-increase-the-upload-limit-for-files-on-a-symfony-2-form) question.

Comment: post_max_size = 200M in my php.ini, but when I call phpinfo(), I can see post_max_size = 2M. I don't know where this 2M come from...

Comment: Very strange, check in this file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini , there are more than two php.ini file exists. try to run this commmand in ubuntu "locate php.ini"

Comment: In doubt, I located and edited ALL the php.ini on my server. phpinfo() still shows 2M instead of 200M...

Comment: Can you share content of /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ?